# Rotate only subview of a uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios7, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate, uideviceorientation

I read up other questions and it isn't very clear, as to what I could do about this problem. 
Decided to ask anyway.

So I have a UIViewController, wherein I block auto-rotation.

I bring up one of the subviews added to the controller. Now, I rotate the device. And *this UIView should change orientation*, I will use autolayout to support all orientations on this view alone.

Is this possible?

What I tried is to, listen for device orientation changes, and then send the orientation to the subview and then was thinking probably `transform`, but that won't be accurate and it is probably a lot of work.

Any clue?

Comment: Well yes. I will put up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, there isn't any direct method without using another view controller to hitch the view to. Add a new `UIViewController` and make your `UIView` the view controller's view. Add your rotation parameters/methods to the newly made view controller.

So its not the best solution because I have to now present that view from a view controller which is adding more code. That's kinda fundamental to a `UIView`. It can't handle itself unless you write hacks and override your view's behavior.

Another solution is to listen to changes in interface orientations and then relayout your view based on that change.